# Commenting on Page reviews from graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

Is it possible to post a comment on facebook page review?

I already have facebook page reviews, but the graph api endpoint for rating is not returning their Ids, so that i can use comment endpoint to post comment. 
How can i get the rating with ids?

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825511/commenting-on-facebook-page-ratings-reviews-via-graph-api) question but the answer is not working.

Comment: What do you mean, it is not returning ids? That doesn’t make any sense, an object id is the basis for dealing with any object via the API. What exact request are you making?

Comment: what have you tried? show your code and debug info.

Comment: Facebook page reviews model has reviewer id, i need post/review id so that i can use it to post comment.

Comment: let me share the request and response with you

Comment: Here is the http get request as mentioned in above [link](https://prnt.sc/iau14m) with required parameters. and [here](http://prntscr.com/iau27h) is the response without Id's

Comment: @CBroe please check request and response.

Comment: @luschn i have upload images of request and response json

Comment: The parameter name is `fields`, not `field` ... (And the query string starts with a question mark, the ampersand separates multiple name=value pairs from one another.)

Comment: i rearranged parameters, yeah "fields" is returning the desired result. Thank you :)  the post i was following which is mentioned above has 'field" in it.

Comment: which end-point you would use to give feedback about rating. can you please give detail. thank's @DanyalMalik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45072115/5726350) i was following.

You have to make http get request on

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/{PageID}/ratings?fields=open_graph_story&access_token={PageAccessToken} 
to get detailed response. Make sure the parameter is "fields" not "field"